# showSaveDialogSync with openDirectory opens file picker in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using [showSaveDialogSync](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowsavedialogsyncbrowserwindow-options) to open a directory picker in Electron. For some reason Windows opens a file picker instead. Does anyone know what I might miss here?

Here is the code with my options:

```js
const options = {
  title: 'Select Directory',
  message: 'Select Directory',
  properties: ['openDirectory',
               'createDirectory',
               'treatPackageAsDirectory',
               'dontAddToRecent']
};

return remote.dialog.showSaveDialogSync(remote.getCurrentWindow(),
                    options as SaveDialogSyncOptions);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just realized the function I should use is called `showOpenDialogSync`. Even if I wanted to use it in a "save directory"-context, this is the function to go with.